# SharePoint 2010 Broken links report

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

How to find Broken Links in SharePoint 2010 Site collection.With Out using SharePoint Designer

Answer (score 0):

try broken link manager from quipoint

link [here](https://store.qipoint.com/product-p/sp14-00-links.htm)